# Is the temporary AWS credentials remains valid even after user is logged out from AWS Cognito?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, jwt

I am using AWS Cognito user pool for authentication in my java application. In my case I am exchanging the JWT token with temporary AWS Credentials, with the configuration of time to live for about 1 hour.
Suppose let's say a logged in user after 15 minutes logs out of the application, what happens to my temporary AWS credentials? Is it still valid for the next 45 minutes?
If so, is there a way to make the temporary AWS credentials invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported. The only way to invoke temporary credentials would be to [deny access to all existing temporary credential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_revoke-sessions.html).